# Why when running this query the values from prc_sum in the where statement appear to all be 100? (Even though I specified to be different to 100)

Tags: sql

> I want to see if there is any error on the calculations I made, so I am summing the percentages to ensure they sum to 100. I include a WHERE clause to filter by the values which are different to 100 to see if there is any error, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT 
      south/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100 AS prc_south,
      west/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100 AS prc_west,
      northeast/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100 AS prc_northeast,
      midwest/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100 AS prc_midwest,
      (south/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)+
      (west/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)+
      (northeast/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)+
      (midwest/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100) AS sum_prc
      FROM tutorial.us_housing_units 
    WHERE  ((south/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)+
           (west/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)+
           (northeast/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)+
           (midwest/ (south + midwest + northeast + west)*100)) != 100
```

> I expected to retrieve values which sum_pcr is not 100. However when I run this it only retrieves values which sum_pcr is 100. >

Comment: multiply everything by `1.0`

Comment: doesn't work drum. Is what I am asking making sense?

Comment: not at all because you didn't provide enough context

Comment: Will do next time I post, twas the first time. Thanks for your support!